# Conversion time from string

Tags: python, datetime

I have a problem with time conversion in Python:
I try to do this:

```
from datetime import datetime
date_object = datetime.strptime('12:29:31.181', '%H:%M:%S')
```

And I receive an error: "ValueError: unconverted data remains: .181"

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add [`%f`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) for microseconds:

```
In [335]:

from datetime import datetime
date_object = datetime.strptime('12:29:31.181', '%H:%M:%S.%f')
print(date_object)
1900-01-01 12:29:31.181000
```

Your format string has to consume all the characters in the passed in string, if any are still remaining then the `ValueError` is raised.